# Can't access dependency object fields in require.js - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, undefined, js-amd

I have created module

myModule.js

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
    return {
        init: function(){
            $('.test').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : "js/",
    paths : {
        jquery : 'lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1',
        myModule : 'lib/modules/myModule
    },
    shim : {

    }
});
```

Now I want to use mymodule.init function in other module in proper place (lets say after AJAX load)

```
require(['jquery', 'myModule'],function($, myModule){
    ...
        myModule.init();
    ...
});
```

Here I have an error:

```
Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `myModule.js` you call `require`. You should call `define` instead so that your module is defined. A `define` call with a first argument that is a dependency list and a second argument that is a function is somewhat like a `require` call with the same arguments but *additionally* defines your module.

Comment: Stupid mistake. Thanks :)